# source code cleanup

Tags: code-cleanup

I have working on a web app for almost 2 years now and a lot unnecessary code(c#, html, js, css ) has accumulated in it. I have been trying to clean it up for a while now but with not great success.

Can you guys sugest ways(tools) by which i speed up this process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should try using [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper). Should work fine with Visual Studio.

Comment: any other tools for css, js and html that you know of

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called [refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring). Most IDEs provide automated support for it to a greater or lesser extent (depending on the language too) - check out yours.

It's no silver bullet - you still have to think, plan, write unit/functional tests to ensure you are not breaking anything, etc. But there are known methods and processes in place, which help you a lot.

Comment: i use visual studio 2008, anything specific to that IDE that you know about

Comment: @Vinay, it surely supports basic refactorings for C#, I am not sure about the other languages. You may want to have a look at [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) which is a commercial plugin, but at least for C++ it is worth its price - I have not used it with C# though.